# Input axis defined but not working

Tags: unity, c#, input, keyboard

I'm trying to use a simple code example to move a square object like this:

```
public GameObject note1;
Vector2 move;

void Update()
{
    // move with keyboard
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Debug.Log(x);
    Debug.Log(y);

    move = new Vector2(x, y);

    Debug.Log(move);

    note.transform.Translate(move * 1 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I check my configuration in the project settings and input manager:

[image: Input manager screenshot]

But I"m confused about three things:

- Why do I have 2 declarations for Horizontal and Vertical input?
- Why does my Keyboard not move the square, even though I have the config ready and I'm using matching strings in my code?
- Why does the `Debug.Log` always report (0, 0)?

Comment: The two declarations for horizontal and vertical input give you multiple synonymous controls — so pressing the arrow keys OR wasd OR using the analog stick on a gamepad will all work to move your character.

Comment: What is note and where do you get/ assign it?

Comment: I note that you've changed the second Horizontal input from its default values. "Type" for that one should be "Joystick Axis" not "Key or Mouse Button" like its keyboard counterpart. But that error does not account for the symptoms you report.

Comment: Your public variable note1 is a different one than the one you use in update